# Видео-фон или как убрать загрузку под мобильные устройства

Tags: javascript, css, html5, видео

Под мобильные устройства постоянно грузит видео, даже если ставить `display: none`
Как убрать загрузку на мобильных устройствах? То есть убрать `autoplay`..
Я знаю, что по-умолчанию видео не грузиться на мобильных устройствах.
Если я убираю autoplay, сразу же моментальнаю загрузка идет на мобилках, но только ставлю, 1-1,5 минуту(-ы) грузит

Comment: Вам наверное лучше будет не убирать, а добавлять, а так суть одна, делаете проверку на ширину экрана, и в зависимости от результата выполняете действие

Comment: Я подумал только что,  и сам решил свой вопрос.. Странно, почему раньше не додумался про это:
`$('#video-ap')[0].play();`
Прописал айди к видео, через jQuery обратился к этому айди и прописал `play();`. После полной загрузки страницы, только тогда включаем видео.
То есть, такой вид:
`$(document).ready(function() {$('#video-ap')[0].play();});`
Ну и да.. убираем autoplay у видео.

Comment: @Hikikomori Да, можно и так. Я про это знал, но это был последний вариант, который я бы хотел использовать, но спасибо за быстрый ответ ;)